# call a javascript when i'm clicking a button?

Tags: javascript, html, buttonclick

I declared a button with a onclick event that should call a javascript function. But it doesn't work. I did research that kind of problem and found some solutions but these haven't worked.
Thanks for the feedback.

Something like that

```
<section class='container_home_counter'>
             <h1>Live Counter</h1><br>                                             
             <button onclick:examplefunction();>Start Counter</button>
        </section>
```

the javascript looks like that:

```
(function($) {
    var reverse = function(value) {
    return value.split('').reverse().join('')...
```

Comment: Did you research about the syntax?

Comment: Don't make up your own JS syntax. Never. Of course it doesn't work.

Comment: `onclick="examplefunction();"` And where is this function defined?

Comment: What's the right syntax ?

Comment: Too lazy to use google, right?

Comment: function examplefunction() {
  var reverse = function(value) {
    return value.split('').reverse().join('');
  }; like that ?

Answer (score 4):

Change this line to:

```
 <button onclick:examplefunction();>Start Counter</button>
```

to this:

```
 <button onclick="examplefunction()">Start Counter</button>
```

and then you must have a function in javascript:

```
function examplefunction() {
    ....
}
```